# awk printing out an associative array with OFS

Tags: awk, gawk

I have the following `awk` code. It first determines the field numbers of interest in the header line and then it prints the output of those fields. The issue is that I am using an associative array to keep the field numbers of interest and thus I print out in the `for` loop and not using `print` but rather `printf`. Its problem is that it adds the separator also at the end of the line.

Is there any simple way around this (without *e.g.* running through the output again and removing the additional separators)? Or is there a better way to print out the fields the numbers of which are stored in an array?

```bsh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = ","; OFS = ","
        no_headers = 2; headers[1] = "header1"; headers[2] = "header3"
        k = 0
    }

    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=no_headers; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=NF; j++) {
                s = gensub(/"/, "", "g", $j)
                if (s==headers[i]) { col_no[++k] = j }
            }
        }
    }

    NR>1 {
        for (i=1; i<=k; i++) { printf "%s,", $col_no[i] }
        print ""
    }' test_awk.txt
```

a test file looks like this

```
"header1","header2","header3","header4"
"a","b","c",4
1,"b",,"d"
"a","2","c","d"
```

and my output at present looks like this

```
"a","c",
1,,
"a","c",
```

but I want it to look like this (*i.e.*, no trailing delimiters)

```
"a","c"
1,
"a","c"
```

Comment: I commend your wanting to do this with awk (and I am personally very fond of awk!), but [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) might save you some time and effort here: `mlr --csv cut -f header1,header3 test_awk.txt`. Miller will respect the header row even through sorting and filtering, and will account for many special cases (like commas and quotes _inside_ a field) that you'd otherwise have to handle in your Awk program. Look at the `--quote-original` and related options in the manual page if you _need_ the quotes in your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `printf()` statement to remove the `,` from the format specifier and add it inside the `{..}` part. Use a ternary operator to append the `,` if not for the last field

```
printf "%s", (i==k) ? $col_no[i] : $col_no[i]","
```

Comment: Even `[…] $col_no[i] OFS` should work, avoiding hard-coding the separator, since it's already defined at the top. Great tip!